# Выравнивание vertical-align в таблице (firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, выравнивание

Что бы вертикально выровнять текст применил такой прием:

```
adress_wrap {
  display: table;
}
.adress_wrap span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

В chrome работает, а в firefox - нет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо `min-height` используйте `height`

Пример

```css
.adress_wrap {
  display: table;
  height: 65px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.adress_wrap span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="adress_wrap">
  <span>вертикально выровнять текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!